# sending data to other domain by laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

I would like to know if this is possible in laravel. I'm a codeigniter developer. I found out that codeigniter cannot 
allow to receive any data from other domain because I enable the csrf. I need to disable first the csrf to communicate outside of my domain.

I don't know if this is possible in laravel that can communicate to other domain without disabling the csrf.
If you have tutorials that can guide me using laravel. Can I ask the link of it? I'm just hoping for your advice for this.

Comment: have to tried Guzzle ? https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: I will try this. thanks

Comment: So you want a form that is outside laravel to be able to POST / PUT into a laravel route?

Comment: @Pitchinnate Is it applicable to laravel to use that idea by using form outside laravel?

Comment: You could do that, however, normally if you are posting from an external system you would set up Laravel more like a REST Api.

Comment: @Pitchinnate thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel you have a `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware with a `$except` property. Here you can put the URIs that should ignore the CSRF token

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, you want to do a POST on a Laravel app without CSRF protection?

Comment: sorry for late reply. no. I have a codeigniter form that will send data to laravel, but i dont have an idea, is laravel accepting a data without disabling a csrf(token)?

Comment: Ok so by default, Laravel is protected with the CSRF token on any POST, PUT, DELETE method. But if you want to POST on foo/bar, just had foo/bar in the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware.

Comment: thank you. Honestly, im new in laravel. trying hard to study it.

Comment: No apologies for being new, everybody makes mistake :P if my answer helped, don't forget to upvote and/or mark as solved...